# Создание виртуальной страници в корне сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess

Пытаюсь сделать профили как ВК. На site.com/id?{№} работает хорошо, но хочу сократить и сделать на site.com/{№}. Не создавать же для каждого пользователя файл профиля...
Такой вариант тоже недопустим (site.com/?{№}). Как это можно сделать? Для htaccess не нашел таких правил или плохо искал. Спасибо

Comment: Правила не надо искать, надо изучать синтаксис mod_rewrite и самому писать. А лучше сразу написать роутер на используемом языке программирования и обойтись вообще без htaccess

Comment: @wirtwelt, в ВК к профилю можно обратиться по прямому url (site.com{№профиля}). Содержание ? в запросе уже не то что нужно

Comment: Благодаря ModRewrite вы можете превратить внешний запрос `site.ru/351` во внутренний запрос `site.ru/index.php?profile=351` одним простым правилом. Внешний переход будет попадать в ваш файл index.php (или любой другой, вы сами указываете - в какой), а ID пользователя можно считать из $_GET['id'] без всяких проблем. Как правильно сказал @andreymal - внимательно изучите синтаксис ModRewrite и поймете, насколько это гибкий и универсальный механизм

Answer (score 0):

Да, спасибо большое. Это работает. Оставлю тут, вдруг кому пригодится

```
    <?
require './include/header/mainhead.php';
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = str_replace("/", "", $url);
$dir    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$files = scandir($dir);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    if(strstr($url, $files[$i])) {require $url. '/index.php'; exit;}
}
if($url == NULL) {require 'main/main.php';}
else {; require 'profile.php';}
?>
```